# Running app on real device vs emulator

Tags: android, android-sqlite

General question: I have database app (which create database and allow to input data into it). When run on emulator (Nexus 7 API 22 Android 5.0.2) runs fine but when same app runs on real device ASUS AOSP On Flo Android 5.1.1 API 22 is crashing. Running app on other real device Sony E5823 Android 6.0.1 API 23 it runs fine.

EDIT:

logcat output:

`09-27 08:57:50.318 544-572/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.linux.site.mrt.mydatabaseexample/.MainActivity: +467ms
09-27 08:57:50.341 894-894/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1
09-27 08:57:50.355 894-894/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
09-27 08:57:50.355 894-894/? D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.
09-27 08:57:50.359 894-894/? I/InputAttributes: InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified
09-27 08:57:50.407 894-894/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
09-27 08:58:01.265 10240-10240/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: results_table
09-27 08:58:01.267 10240-10240/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-27 08:58:01.268 10240-10240/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.linux.site.mrt.mydatabaseexample, PID: 10240
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: results_table (code 1): , while compiling: select * from results_table
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                       at com.linux.site.mrt.mydatabaseexample.DatabaseHelper.getAllData(DatabaseHelper.java:128)
                                                       at com.linux.site.mrt.mydatabaseexample.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-27 08:58:01.270 544-1123/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.linux.site.mrt.mydatabaseexample/.MainActivity`

Comment: Can you show us the locgat?

Comment: I suspect that you are creating database in asset folder and accessing it.You have to dynamically create database/table.This is a common problem across all samsung device or any device that modifies the OS

Comment: @kgandroid database is created in data/data/packageName...or should be created. I am using `db.execSQL(create table" + TABLE_NAME + (...` code

Comment: seems that you are creating it dynamically...post your crash log

Comment: no such table results_table...that means the table is not created properly

Comment: any idea why it is not created on some of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ass seen in the logcat , the tabel `tabel_Result` not found in the database, if you clear data stored on emulator, same error will appear. i think you need to

Comment: to be precise [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862949/cant-create-database-in-android) is correct solution.